# Django prefetch_related over 3 models (one "relationship Model"

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to aggregate and Output Data from my Models to my HTML Page

**Models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

class ClientDB(models.Model):
    Hostname= models.CharField(max_length=50,primary_key=True)
    User= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
class VULDB(models.Model):
    VID=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    CVELIST=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    CVSScore=models.FloatField(max_length=5)
    Serverity=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    Title=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    Summary=models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class ClientVULDB(models.Model):
    
    Hostname= models.ForeignKey(ClientDB, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    VID=models.ForeignKey(VULDB, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Path=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    isActive=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
               fields=['Hostname', 'VID'], name='unique_migration_host_combination' # legt 
            )
        ]
```

I would like to create a view that Output and aggregate Data in the Model to my HTML Template. I need help how I can aggregate (and put it in an Queryset?) the data like in the [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owrv9.png)

**I've got two Querysets which Query the Models:**

```
q1=VULDB.objects.filter().values_list('Title','clientvuldb__Hostname')
    q2=ClientDB.objects.filter().values_list('Hostname', 'Benutzer', 'clientvuldb__VID')
```

**The Output is as follows:**

<QuerySet [('Test-VUL', 'Host2'),
('Test-VUL2', 'Host2'),
('Test-VUL3', 'Host1'),
('Test-Vul4', 'Host2')]>

<QuerySet [ ('Host1', 'User1', 1),
('Host2', 'User2', 1)]

**I would like to render**

Host1,  Test-VUL3

Host2, Test-VUL, Test-VUL2, Test-VUL3

Comment: Exactly what do you want to render?

Comment: So I've got 2 Query sets:
q1=VULDB.objects.filter().values_list('Title','clientvuldb__Hostname')
q2=ClientDB.objects.filter().values_list('Hostname', 'User', 'clientvuldb__VID')

The Output is: 
<QuerySet [('Test-VUL', 'Host2'), 
('Test-VUL', 'Host2'), 
('Test-VUL', 'Host1'), 
('Security Vulnerability CVE-2018-1285 for log4net', 'Host2')]> 



<QuerySet [, 
('Host1', 'User1', 1), 
('Host2', 'User2', 2405), 
('Host2', 'User2', 2705), 

I want to Render:
Host1,  Test-VUL
Host2, Test-VUL, Test-VUL2, Security Vulnerability CVE-2018-1285 for log4net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `.values(..)` or `.values_list(..)`, it will erode the model layer.

work with:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

qs = VULDB.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('clientvuldb_set', ClientVULDB.objects.select_related('VID'))
)
```

in the template, render with:

```
<ul>
{% for item in qs %}
  <li>{{ qs.Hostname }}
  <ul>
  {% for subitem in item.clientvuldb_set.all %}
    <li>{{ subitem.VID.Title }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `title` instead of <s>`Title`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Models normally have no `Db` suffix. A model is not a table, it is stored in a relational database as a table, but even then it has extra logic like validators, managers, etc.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help :) 
I changed my HTML to your Code. (only difference im using a td), i got an error and added qs in the second for {% for subitem in  qs %}. I dont get any Data shown when opening my HTML Page. I dont know it the prefetch returns the correct Data right know if I do print(qs.count) I get returned 2 (Ive got 2 Vulnerbilitys but want to display all the Clients (6) on my HTML Page.

Comment: @xMonkey1337: sorry, I made a typo, see fix.

Comment: Thanks for the Update. Can you explaine me how the Python Code "joins" the third DB. Because I cant see how :) Very Appriciated

Comment: @xMonkey1337: `.select_related('VID')`. :)