# Django prefetch_related with 3 not directly related Models

Tags: django

I`ve got three Models in my Django APP.

**Models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

class client(models.Model):
    hostname= models.CharField(max_length=50,primary_key=True)
    user= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
class vul(models.Model):
    VID=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    CVELIST=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    CVSScore=models.FloatField(max_length=5)
    Serverity=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    Title=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    Summary=models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class clientvul(models.Model):
    
    hostname= models.ForeignKey(client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    VID=models.ForeignKey(vul, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Path=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    isActive=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
               fields=['hostname', 'VID'], name='unique_migration_host_combination'
            )
        ]



admin.site.register(ClientDB)
admin.site.register(VULDB)
admin.site.register(ClientVULDB)
```

**My View:**

```py
def index(request):
    qs = client.objects.prefetch_related(
          Prefetch('clientvuldb_set', clientvul.objects.select_related('hostname')))
 
    print(qs)
    return render(request, 'browseDB.html', {'data':qs})
```

**My Template**

```html
  <tbody>
          {% for row in data %}
          <tr>
            <td class="hostname">{{ row.hostname}}</td>
            <td class="User">{{ row.user }}</td>
            <td class="Vulnerabilites">
              <select class="form-select" size="4">
                {% for subitem in data%}
                <option>{{ subitem.Title }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
              </select>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success sign" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">Show-Info</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

I want to Displaye the Data grouped By the Hostname on my template:

hostname (client), user(client), Title(vul)

So I don´t know where i can "group" the Data but any help would be appriciated :)

Already asked on StackOverflow:
[Django prefetch_related over 3 models (one "relationship Model"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76189465/django-prefetch-related-over-3-models-one-relationship-model)

but I think I didn`t formulated the Question good.

Comment: well your queryset fetched `hostname`, but your "outer" queryset is already client. Furthermore in the template, you tried to enumerate over data, not its `clientvul_set.all` queryset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `.select_related` the wrong relation, you should fetch `VID`, so:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch


def index(request):
    qs = client.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('clientvul_set', clientvul.objects.select_related('VID'))
    )
    return render(request, 'browseDB.html', {'data': qs})
```

then in the template you can work with:

```
<tbody>
  {% for row in data %}
  <tr>
    <td class="hostname">{{ row.hostname}}</td>
    <td class="User">{{ row.user }}</td>
    <td class="Vulnerabilites">
      <select class="form-select" size="4">
        {% for subitem in row.clientvul_set.all %}
            <option>{{ subitem.VID.Title }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success sign" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">Show-Info</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Your `clientvul` model however acts as a junction table for a many-to-many relation between `client` and `vul`. You can span a [**`ManyToManyField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) on the `client` model with:

```
class client(models.Model):
    # …
    vuls = models.ManyToManyField(
        'vul',
        through='clientvul',
        related_name='clients'
    )
```

Then you can simplify this to:

```
def index(request):
    qs = client.objects.prefetch_related('vuls')
    return render(request, 'browseDB.html', {'data': qs})
```

and in the template, use:

```
<tbody>
  {% for row in data %}
  <tr>
    <td class="hostname">{{ row.hostname}}</td>
    <td class="User">{{ row.user }}</td>
    <td class="Vulnerabilites">
      <select class="form-select" size="4">
        {% for subitem in row.vuls.all %}
            <option>{{ subitem.Title }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success sign" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">Show-Info</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`ClientVul`</s> to `clientvul`.

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `cvs_score` instead of <s>`CVSScore`</s>.

Comment: The client and user are shown. But it dosen't display any Titles. Do I even fetch the Titles? Because I never adress the vul Model in my view

Comment: @jonat-han: you do this with `subitem.VID.Title` so you access these through `.VID`.

Comment: @jonat-han: you need to access the `clientvul`s with `in data.clientvul_set.all`, using `in data` will *not* work since a `Client` object is not iterable.

Comment: @jonat-han: it should be `'vuls'`, since the `related_name` is `vuls`.

Comment: Yeah sorry saw it myself and fixed it but
it still wont load the titels from the vul model.

Comment: @jonat-han: sorry, it is `row.vuls.all`.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late questin. How would i access the Data in the clientvul junction Table? `row` has the client Data, and `subitem` the vul Data.