# Display Data in Template from Django Model

Tags: django

I´m Trying to Access Data from my "junction" model `clientvul` in my Template.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

class client(models.Model):
    client= models.CharField(max_length=50,primary_key=True)
    user= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    vuls = models.ManyToManyField(
        'vul',
        through='clientvul',
        related_name='client'
    )
    
 
class vul(models.Model):
    vid=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    cvelist=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cvsscore=models.FloatField(max_length=5)
    serverity=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    summary=models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class clientvul(models.Model):
    
    client= models.ForeignKey(client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vid=models.ForeignKey(vul, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    path=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    isactive=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
               fields=['client', 'vid'], name='unique_migration_host_combination' 
            )
        ]



admin.site.register(client)
admin.site.register(vul)
admin.site.register(clientvul)
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    qs = client.objects.prefetch_related('vuls')
    return render(request, 'browseDB.html', {'data':qs})
```

**Template**

```
      {% for row in data %}
      <table class="table">
        <thead class="table-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Hostname</th>
            <th scope="col">User</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <td class="Hostname">{{ row.client }}</a></td>
            <td class="User">{{ row.user }}</td>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">Title</th>
                  <th scope="col">Severity</th>
                  <th scope="col">CVE</th>
                  <th scope="col">Path</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {% for subitem in row.vuls.all %}
                <tr>
                  <td class="Title" >{{ subitem.title }}</td>
                  <td class="Severity">{{ subitem.serverity }}</td>
                  <td class="CVE" >{{ subitem.cvelist }}</td>
                  <td class="Path" >{{ subitem.path }}</td>

                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <br>
            {% endfor %}
```

The problem is that `<td class="Path" >{{ subitem.path }}</td>` stays empty.
I don´t know how I can reference the related path from the junction Model `clientvul`.

Related Question: [Django prefetch_related with 3 not directly related Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76261784/django-prefetch-related-with-3-not-directly-related-models)

Answer (score 0):

I found a Workaround provided by @willem-van-onsem

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    qs = client.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('clientvul_set', clientvul.objects.select_related('VID')))
    return render(request, 'browseDB.html', {'data':qs})
```

**template**

```
     {% for row in data %}
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
      <table class="table">
        <thead class="table-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">client</th>
            <th scope="col">User</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <td class="client">{{ row.client }}</a></td>
            <td class="User">{{ row.user }}</td>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">Title</th>
                  <th scope="col">Severity</th>
                  <th scope="col">CVE</th>
                  <th scope="col">Path</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {% for subitem in row.clientvul_set.all  %}
                <tr>
                  <td class="Title" >{{ subitem.vid.title }}</td>
                 
                    {% if "Critical" == subitem.vid.serverity %}
                      <td class="Severity"><span class="badge bg-dark">Critical</span></td>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if subitem.vid.serverity == "High" %}
                      <td class="Severity"><span class="badge bg-danger">High</span></td>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if subitem.vid.serverity == "Medium" %}
                      <td class="Severity"><span class="badge bg-warning text-dark">Medium</span></td>
                    {% endif %}
                  <td class="CVE" >
                    <a href=https://www.cve.org/CVERecord?id={{ subitem.VID.CVELIST }}>{{ subitem.VID.CVELIST }}</a>
                  </td>
                  <td class="Path" >{{ subitem.path }}</td>

                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
            </table>
           
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
            {% endfor %}
```